# custom pivot table on manytomany relationship returning no results

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I'm converting an old project from vanilla PHP to laravel and the first problem is that the database doesn't conform to the standard naming conventions. I'd prefer to keep the database as is and adapt my laravel models to it, then update the database once I switch to the laravel code.

This is just one of many many-to-many relationships that I need to implement. The User model needs to have a many-to-many relationship with the Payee model. I have a pivot table:

userpay:

- up_user  (foreign key for users table)
- up_payee (foreign key for payees table
- up_name  (each user can give the payee a different nickname)
- up_del   (for soft deletes)

My User model is includes:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_name',
        'email',
        'user_pass',
        'hash',
        'user_curr',
        'fiscal',
        'user_date'
    ];

    public function payees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Payee::class, 'userpay', 'up_user', 'up_pay')
            ->whereNull('up_del')
            ->withPivot(['up_name', 'up_del']);
    }
}
```

My Payee model includes:

```php
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Payee extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        protected $table = 'payees';
        protected $primaryKey = 'pay_id';
        protected $fillable = [
            'name'
        ];
    
        public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'userpay', 'up_pay', 'up_user')
                ->whereNull('up_del')
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->withPivot('up_name', 'up_del');
        }
    }
```

`User::find(1)->payees()->attach(16, ['up_name' => 'eloquent', 'up_del' => 0])` works to create a new relationship record. The problem is when I query the data. `User::find(1)->payees` should return 10 records, but it just shows `all::[]`.

As I understand from the docs, I don't need to define the userpay table as a model explicitly, but I'm not sure what else I should be looking at. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So far, the only way I can get this working is to rename all the tables and columns to standard. Even just renaming the pivot table and columns isn't enough. It tries to look for 'user_user_id' on the pivot, apparently adding the class to the local id column name.

Comment: I found it. I used telescope to see the actual query being run and realised that the 'whereNull' condition was culling all the data because my code always used '0' as the active condition. That should have been obvious, but I've become so used to dealing with complicated issues that I no longer see the obvious.